# Google Forms, protecting information

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It seems that you CANNOT restrict access to forms by groups, but can you check whether the accessor is in a group when you go to populate a form? I have one dropdown in my tool that is populated from a spreadsheet, I was wondering whether the form can check who is trying to access it before it populates that dropdown.

Code, because the question wants code (all of this works except I've chopped up the IDs):

```
// call your form and connect to the drop-down item
  var form = FormApp.openById("1JMfe31jHE4R8StPy");

  var namesList = form.getItemById("18500").asListItem();




// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1zV0cUzUg0mMM');
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("Input");

  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var namesValues = names.getRange("F3:F11").getValues();

  var studentNames = [];

  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)    
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      studentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  namesList.setChoiceValues(studentNames);

 // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row 
  var namesValues = names.getRange("A29:A45").getValues();

  var studentNames = [];

  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++)    
    if(namesValues[i][0] != "")
      studentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];

  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  namesList = form.getItemById("781187400").asListItem();
  namesList.setChoiceValues(studentNames);


}
```

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: When a Google Form is open in "View" mode, for user input, it can't run any code.  It can run code when in "Edit" mode, but will the people filling out the Form have edit access?  When are you running this code?  If you have one Form for everyone filling out the Form, then editing a question for one person could affect how the Form opens up for another person, and you wouldn't be able to guarantee what content opened for which user.  If every user had their own Form, that would be different, but then if you want a central place for all the data to go, you'd need to somehow deal with that.